# How to use multiple WHERE in SQL?

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

```
Table A: ticket
RoundID | PlayerID | num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 | num6

Table B: lotteryresult
RoundID | num1 | num2 | num3 | num4 | num5 | num6
```

I have created a selector as:

```
SELECT roundID, UserInfo_ID, num1, num2, num3, num4 , num5, num6
FROM ticket JOIN lotteryresult ON ticket.roundID = lotteryresult.roundID
WHERE...; -- I want to match num1 to num6 to find matched numbers
```

The problem is I don't know what to do to match num1 to num6, and the difficulty is that a number located in num1 at Table A (e.g. '6') could be located at num3 at Table B.

So what can I do to match these numbers?

Comment: can the results be provided as a group of six numbers or they have to come from a table?

Comment: Can you add , say, 3 players on 3 rounds (that would be 9 rows for `ticket`) and 3 rounds for `lottery result` to your question, so I don' need to type any results from my side?. I have a solution, but I'm too lazy to create test data ...

Comment: You can only have a single `where` in a select, if you want multiple conditions, use `AND` and `OR`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the goal is:

```
where
    a.num1 in (b.num1, b.num2, b.num3, b.num4, b.num5, b.num6) or
    a.num2 in (b.num1, b.num2, b.num3, b.num4, b.num5, b.num6) ...
```

Or maybe you're wanting to count matches?

```
select *
from ticket t inner join lotteryresult r on r.roundID = t.roundID
    cross apply (
        select sum(case when pvt.num in (r.num1, r.num2, r.num3, r.num4, r.num5, r.num6) then 1 end
        from (values (t.num1), (t.num2), (t.num3), (t.num4), (t.num5), (t.num6k)) pvt(num)
) m(matches)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want either `ticket.num1 = lotteryresult.num6` or `ticket.num1 = lotteryresult.num3` to match, and it's just like that:
`ticket.num1 = lotteryresult.num6 or ticket.num1 = lotteryresult.num3`
and a shorter version of that is
`ticket.num1 in (lotteryresult.num6, lotteryresult.num3)`
and you can add more columns of `lotteryresult` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Pivot both ticket table and result table vertically; join those pivoted tables on round id and the one of the six numbers resulting out of pivoting vertically, and count.

Here goes:

```
WITH
-- some input data ...
ticket(roundid , playerid , num1 , num2 , num3 , num4 , num5 , num6) AS (
            SELECT 1,1, 5,13,22,27,42,49
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,1, 5,13,22,27,42,49
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,1, 5,13,22,27,42,49
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,2, 6,14,23,28,44,48
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,2, 6,14,23,28,44,48
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,2, 6,14,23,28,44,48
  UNION ALL SELECT 1,3, 7,15,24,29,43,47
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,3, 7,15,24,29,43,47
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,3, 7,15,24,29,43,47
)
,
-- some input data ...
lotteryresult(roundid , num1 , num2 , num3 , num4 , num5 , num6) AS (
            SELECT 1,       5,    23,    29,34,36,40
  UNION ALL SELECT 2,       1,    12,    16,23,31,48
  UNION ALL SELECT 3,       4,    12,    13,19,31,46
)
,
-- real query starts here, replace comma above with "WITH"
-- need a series of integers ...
i(i) AS (
            SELECT 1
  UNION ALL SELECT 2
  UNION ALL SELECT 3
  UNION ALL SELECT 4
  UNION ALL SELECT 5
  UNION ALL SELECT 6
)
,
unpivot_tk AS (
  SELECT
    roundid
  , playerid
  , CASE i
      WHEN 1 THEN num1
      WHEN 2 THEN num2
      WHEN 3 THEN num3
      WHEN 4 THEN num4
      WHEN 5 THEN num5
      WHEN 6 THEN num6
    END AS num
  FROM ticket CROSS JOIN i
)
,
unpivot_res AS (
  SELECT
    roundid
  , CASE i
      WHEN 1 THEN num1
      WHEN 2 THEN num2
      WHEN 3 THEN num3
      WHEN 4 THEN num4
      WHEN 5 THEN num5
      WHEN 6 THEN num6
    END AS num
  FROM lotteryresult CROSS JOIN i
)
SELECT
  tk.roundid
, tk.playerid
, COUNT(*) AS hits
FROM unpivot_tk tk
JOIN unpivot_res USING(roundid,num)
GROUP BY
  tk.roundid
, tk.playerid
ORDER BY
  tk.roundid
, tk.playerid
-- out  roundid | playerid | hits 
-- out ---------+----------+------
-- out        1 |        1 |    1
-- out        1 |        2 |    1
-- out        1 |        3 |    1
-- out        2 |        2 |    2
-- out        3 |        1 |    1
```